# cmake - How to change compile_commands.json output location

Tags: cmake

Here's an example C++ project structure:

```
- {root}
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - build/
        - compile_commands.json  <-- This file gets generated  
    - src/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - files here
    - compile_commands.json  <-- This is where I want compile_commands.json to be built to
```

If I build the project, it creates a "compile_commands.json" file in the "build" folder. But I actually want it underneath "{root}". Is there a way to specify the location of compile_commands.json? Or do I have to just copy it manually?

These are the command(s) that I typically use to build a project

(If cd'ed into {root})
`cmake . -B build`
alternative:
`cd {root}/build && cmake ..`

In both cases, compile_commands.json is added to the build folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify the location of compile_commands.json?

There is no way. I believe the path for `compile_commands.json` generated when [CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) is set is [hardcoded](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/98d065740ef47a8da859751430c04284b1e3d9e5/Source/cmGlobalNinjaGenerator.cxx#L1218) to be [inside](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/98d065740ef47a8da859751430c04284b1e3d9e5/Source/cmake.cxx#L2103) [`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html).

Just create a symlink `compile_commands.json -> ./build/compile_commands.json`.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. In that case, I'll have to write around the problem. Thank you for the source link, by the way!

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, but if you use neovim as editor, and you want to use lspconfig with clangd, you need to add this code in your `init.lua`:

```
require('lspconfig').clangd.setup{ init_options = {
   compilationDatabasePath = './build/debug'
 }
}
```

Of course you need to update the path with the one in which you have the `compile_commands.json`.